# Messages.properties file instead of json files with angular translate static file loader

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

Can we use Messages.properties files instead of json files with angular translate static file loader? Are there any other file extensions apart from json that can be used ?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the ngx-translate libryry. I don't think you can use properties with it.

What you can do is to convert dynamically the property-files to a json-format with some JSON library in your backend. And provide them to the frontend via Rest endpint for example.

For example Spring-Java:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/i18n/{lang}")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> fetchLangJson(@PathVariable String lang) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    resourceBundleMessageSource.getBasenameSet().forEach(bn -> {
        map.putAll(fetchPropsAsHashMap(bn + "_" + lang + .properties"));
    });
    JSONObject jsonProps = new JSONObject(map);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(jsonProps.toString(), HttpStatus.OK);
};
```

//fetchPropsAsHashMap - read the properties and converts them to
//HashMap<String, String>

See hier [Ionic3 / Ngx-translate - TranslateHttpLoader with external URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45280901/ionic3-ngx-translate-translatehttploader-with-external-url)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).