# Ionic3 / Ngx-translate - TranslateHttpLoader with external URL

Tags: ionic3, ngx-translate

I'm loading the translation files from the server using TranslateHttpLoader in my app.module.ts like this:

```
export function createTranslateLoader(http: Http) {
   return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, AppConfig.API_URL+'/static/i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
  ...

  imports: [

    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
        deps: [Http]
      }
    }), 

  ],
  ...
})
```

Everything works fine, but i'm wondering if there is a way to catch event when the loader fails to retrieve the language file for whatever reason (server issues, net con etc.) and possibly load a local json file with some default translation strings?

I want to catch this event if the app on the first load fails to grab the language file , and fallback to minimal local json file to just display translated mainetnance page/error page or something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE for Angular >= 4.3**

As new Angular versions use `HttpClient` instead of `Http`, an updated and much shorter version of [mike_t's `CustomTranslateLoader`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45295433/5816097)  would be:

```js
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AppConfig } from './config';


@Injectable()
export class CustomTranslateLoader implements TranslateLoader  {
    contentHeader = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    });

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}
    getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
        const apiAddress = AppConfig.API_URL + `/static/i18n/${lang}.json`;
        return this.httpClient.get(apiAddress, { headers: this.contentHeader })
          .pipe(
            catchError(_ => this.httpClient.get(`/assets/i18n/en.json`))
          );
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for updating this, i changed your answer to be the accepted solution!

Comment: I am getting:
 CustomTranslateLoader cannot be invoked without 'new'

Answer (score 5):

at the end i wrote a custom loader that resolves the requirement:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Response } from "@angular/http";
import { TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { AppConfig } from "./config"
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'; 


@Injectable()
export class CustomTranslateLoader implements TranslateLoader  {
    contentHeader = new Headers({"Content-Type": "application/json","Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"});

    constructor(private http: Http) {}
    getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any>{
        var apiAddress = AppConfig.API_URL+"/static/i18n/"+ lang+".json";
        return Observable.create(observer => {
          this.http.get(apiAddress, { headers: this.contentHeader }).subscribe((res: Response) => {
                    observer.next(res.json());
                    observer.complete();               
                },
            error => {
                //  failed to retrieve from api, switch to local
                this.http.get("/assets/i18n/en.json").subscribe((res: Response) => {
                    observer.next(res.json());
                    observer.complete();               
                })
            }
            );
        }); 
    }
}
```

and in app.module.ts

```
...
import { CustomTranslateLoader } from "../services/trans-loader"
...

@NgModule({
  ...

  imports: [

    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useClass: CustomTranslateLoader,
        deps: [Http]
      }
    }), 

  ],
  ...
})
```

Comment: how will you handle the html part?

Comment: Like this only ? {{'Login' | translate}} ?

Comment: yes, just using a `translate` pipe. Don't forget to add `TranslateModule.forChild()` in your ngmodule imports.

Comment: it's a method of original TranslateLoader that we're overriding here, it gets invoked automatically by ionic when it loads translations using the specified loader

Comment: Ok. Got it. Can you show me your app.component.ts file?

Comment: the only relevant code in app.component.ts is  `this.translate.setDefaultLang('en');` and in case chosen language is different than default `this.translate.use(user_lang);`.  `this.translate` refers to TranslateService, which i import like `import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';`

Comment: Ok, let me try it

Comment: in that service getTranslation() accepts one parameter right? lang? what is the significance of that? from where the value is passed to that function?

Comment: when u call `this.translate.use(lang)` of `TranslateService`  (in my case in app.component.ts) , i believe it invokes the getTranslation() method of the loader with the lang as attribute

Comment: What will be the case if we have multiple .json files stored on that adress?

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE for Angular 12+**

1. Create a new custom translate loader

```js
// loader/customTranslate.loader.ts
import { TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

const LOCAL_URL = 'http://your.url.blanik.me/api';

export class CustomTranslateLoader implements TranslateLoader {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
    const url = `${LOCAL_URL}/assets/i18n/${lang}.json`;

    return this.httpClient.get(url).pipe(catchError((_) => this.httpClient.get(`/assets/i18n/en.json`)));
  }
}
```

2. Update angular app module

```js
// app.module.ts
// {...}
import { TranslateLoader, TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CustomTranslateLoader } from './loader/customTranslate.loader';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, OtherComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    // ...
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useClass: CustomTranslateLoader,
        deps: [HttpClient],
      },
    }),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

3. Add language switch to your component

```html
<select class="form-control" #langauge (change)="translateSite(langauge.value)">
  <option *ngFor="let localization of translateService.getLangs()" [value]="localization"
          [selected]="localization === translateService.currentLang">
    {{ localization }}
  </option>
</select>
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent{
  title = 'your-app-name';

  constructor(public translateService: TranslateService) {
    translateService.addLangs(['en', 'fr', 'pl']);
    translateService.setDefaultLang('en');
  }

  translateSite(langauge: string) {
    this.translateService.use(langauge);
  }
}
```

**Please remember** to set proper CORS on your server and/or (*recommended*) keep your translation file under the same domain.

**Do not add custom CORS headers** in `httpClient`. Otherwise, the browser will prevent reading the file.

Cheers!