# how to work with ngx translate in ionic 3 by external translation url

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

i believe its a timing issue, yet i dont know how to solve it. translate works fine when i use my local files. but when i want to use an external file in a host it seems that the request is doing fine and the translation file comes back as a respond but in the app it only shows the key names. not the values. for clarification here are my codes. **app.module.ts:**

```
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
...
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
          loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
            deps: [HttpClient]
          }
        }),
    ...
    export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
      return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, 'https://www.****.com/generated-asset/app/translations/', '.json');
    }
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, Nav, ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { SplashPage } from '../pages/splash/splash';
import { LanguagesProvider } from '../providers/languages/languages';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})

export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) navCtrl: Nav;
  rootPage: any = HomePage;
  langs: any;
  splash: any;

  constructor(private modalController: ModalController, public langProvide: LanguagesProvider,
    public platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private storage: Storage, translate: TranslateService) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      //splashScreen.hide();
      this.splash = modalController.create(SplashPage);
      this.splash.present();
    });
    storage.ready().then(() => {
      storage.get('languageCode').then((lang) => {
        if (lang) {
          platform.setLang(lang, true);
          translate.setDefaultLang(lang);
          translate.use(lang);
        } else {
          platform.setLang('fa', true);
          translate.setDefaultLang('fa');
          translate.use('fa');
        }
      });
      this.storage.get('myDir').then((dir) => {
        if (dir) {
          platform.setDir(dir, true);
        } else {
          platform.setDir('rtl', true);
        }
      });
    });
    this.getLang();
  }
```

and finally a part of one of my html files. for example **app.html:**

```
<ion-list id="menu-list1">
  <ion-item text-end color="none" menuClose="" (click)="goTo('tourism')" class="mymenu">
    <ion-icon name="globe" item-start></ion-icon>
    {{'tourism' | translate}}
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item text-end color="none" menuClose="" (click)="goTo('blog')" class="mymenu">
    <ion-icon name="laptop" item-start></ion-icon>
    {{'blog' | translate}}
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item text-end color="none" menuClose="" (click)="goToAbout()" class="mymenu">
    <ion-icon name="information-circle" item-start></ion-icon>
    {{'about' | translate}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: The pipe displays the translation as it's known now. Prefer the directive, which will update when the translation is ready. Or avoid displaying the template until the translations are loaded.

Comment: @JBNizet i've used directive yet the result is the same. so your other solution: avoid displaying the template until translations are ready. how should i do that?

Comment: use() returns an Observable. It will emit when the translations are ready.

Comment: this topic:[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45280901/ionic3-ngx-translate-translatehttploader-with-external-url) helped me to solve my problem